# Typescript error on local machine but not on remote test server

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to use Microsoft Fabric's UI tools. This is the error I get on my local machine.

```
/Developer/React/TCV.ts/tcv/src/CategorySelection.tsx(94,9):
Type '(filterText: string, currentPersonas: IPersonaProps[], limitResults?: number | undefined) => IPersonaProps[] | Promise<IPersonaProps[]>' is not assignable to type '(filter: string, selectedItems?: IPersonaProps[] | undefined) => IPersonaProps[] | PromiseLike<IPersonaProps[]>'.
  Types of parameters 'currentPersonas' and 'selectedItems' are incompatible.
    Type 'IPersonaProps[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'IPersonaProps[]'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'IPersonaProps[]'.  TS2322

    92 |       <CompactPeoplePicker
    93 |         // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-bind
  > 94 |         onResolveSuggestions={onFilterChanged}
       |         ^
    95 |         // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-bind
    96 |         onEmptyInputFocus={returnMostRecentlyUsed}
    97 |         getTextFromItem={getTextFromItem}
```

However, when I load my exact same code to codesandbox.io the error disappears and it works fine. My files are the same, and package.json is identical. What can be causing this behavior?

EXAMPLE:
https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-darkness-xypss?file=/src/Search.tsx

Comment: Given that it's complaining about type 'undefined' but only in one environment, my immediate guess is strictNullChecks (or some other strict-ish flag) is turned on for your tsconfig but not in codesandbox's tsconfig

Comment: Thanks @user1713450 that was the issue. If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me also after changing the

```
"strict": false,
```

in tsconfig.json